# elasticsearch java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.formatSegments

Tags: spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, nosuchmethoderror, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm trying this basic elasticsearch [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html) from there guide to use java client API in a spring boot project.

but it gives me the following error when running:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.formatSegments([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

here is my [POM file](https://justpaste.it/4j8yi).

the code:

```
public void retrieveAuditMessages() throws IOException {
        // Create the low-level client
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)
        ).build();

    // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper()
    );

    // Create the API client
    ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    
    SearchResponse<String> search = client.search(s -> s
            .index("logstash-wildfly*")
            .query(q -> q
                    .term(t -> t
                            .field("host")
                            .value(v -> v.stringValue("aboSaadoosh"))
                    )
            ),
            String.class);

    for(Hit<String> hit: search.hits().hits())
    {
        System.out.println(hit.source());
    }
}
```

I guess it's a problem with dependencies, but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm using Elasticsearch version `8.1.1` `java client API` and spring boot `1.5.7.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13` explicitly in the POM file (instead of version `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3` included by `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.1.1`)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to solve it but anyway it worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version of Spring Boot might also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any dependency is added to pom.xml, the corresponding dependencies are also resolved.
In this case, some maven dependency is using some other version of httpclient. That is why this conflict is arising.
Please double check every added dependency and their corresponding dependencies.